# How to generate JSON coverage report with Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode11, xcrun

I've run unit tests from the command line like this:

```
xcodebuild \
    -resultBundlePath Example.xcresult \
    -workspace Example.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Example \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8" \
    test
```

and now I'd like to get the coverage report as JSON, but xccov fails with *Error: unrecognized file format*:

```
xcrun xccov view --json Example.xcresult
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Xcode 11 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes) you'll have to append `--report` too, so in your specific example:

```sh
xcrun xccov view --report --json Example.xcresult
```

The `JSON` format will be the same as the previous one.

Please read [this thread](https://twitter.com/czechboy0/status/1135702721812525056) from Honza Dvorsky ([@czechboy0](https://twitter.com/czechboy0))

Comment: Also, `Example.xcresult` is your target *now*. 

Previously you had to drill down till the `.xccovreport` file and run the command for that bundle, but not anymore. 

So pay attention if you have some paths hardcoded to find the old  `.xccovport`.